# iOS Accurate AudioTimeStamp when rendering Audio Units

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, core-audio

In my AudioInputRenderCallback I'm looking to capture an accurate time stamp of certain audio events. To test my code, I'm inputting a click track @120BPM or every 500 milliseconds (The click is accurate, I checked, and double checked). I first get the decibel of every sample, and check if it's over a threshold, this works as expected. I then take the hostTime from the AudioTimeStamp, and convert it to milliseconds. The first click gets assigned to that static timestamp and the second time through does a calculation of the interval and then reassigns to the static one. I expected to see a 500 interval. To be able to calculate the click correctly I have to be with in 5 milliseconds. The numbers seem to bounce back and forth between 510 & 489. I understand it's not an RTOS, but can iOS be this accurate? Is there any issues with using the mach_absolute_time member of the AudioUnitTimeStamp?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the sampleTime or wordClock fields instead?

Comment: My understanding was that they all represented the same point in time, which means they'd have the same level of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Audio Units are buffer based.  The minimum length of an iOS Audio Unit buffer seems to be around 6 mS.  So if you use the time-stamps of the buffer callbacks, your time resolution or time sampling jitter will be about +- 6 mS.

If you look at the actual raw PCM samples inside the Audio Unit buffer and pattern match the "attack" transient (by threshold or autocorrelation, etc.) you might be able get sub-millisecond resolution.

Comment: I agree & like the approach. Not sure exactly how to implement. If I'm not using the AU timestamp, where does time come from once I've determined which sample it is? (I'm actually already looking at each raw PCM sample.)

Comment: If I've calculated correctly, each buffer is about 1024 samples @ .022 milliseconds each sample @ 44.1k. Each buffer would take about 22 milliseconds to process which is almost exactly what I was reporting 510 - 489.